# Select Column from Table in Django Not Working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to access the **two specific column** from the table in Django it is not Working but When I am trying to access `select *` it is working

**I am using postgresql**

When I am trying to access select all its working this is I am trying to access for particular column

```
def bigdataDatabase(X):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/db_name')
    con = engine.connect()

    result = con.execute(
        "Select Orign,Departure From 'table_name' WHERE index = '" + str(X) + "'")
```

**This is not working**

I have also tried with this

```
    result = con.execute("Select tablename.Orign,tablename.departure From 'table_name' WHERE index = '" + str(X) + "'")
```

**both the above code is not working**

**Programming Error column does not exist**

But When I am executing all this it is working

```
result = con.execute("Select * From 'table_name' WHERE index = '" + str(X) + "'")
```

Comment: Please also include the table schema or your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution of the problem the query should be executed like this

```
result = con.execute('Select "Orign","Departure" From "Table_name" WHERE index = ' + str(X))
```